# Где хранить данные для постов в телеграмм?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Нужно написать бота в котором еженедельно будет рассылка некого материала. Материал будет постоянно дополняться. Вопрос: как реализовать добавление рассылочного материала в бота и где его хранить?
Думаю, может, можно в приватный чат кидать посты, чтобы бот их пересылал, но как по мне - такая себе идея.
Буду рад любому совету!

Comment: Так в базе данных же

Comment: @VladimirGonchar А лучше в бд хранить путь до изображения или само изображение?

Comment: Путь до изображения, само изображение очень часто неоправдано хранить (тем более картинки для постов). Как минимум, картинки могут переиспользоваться, тогда ссылки не занимают место.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можете поробовать через бд, или в текстовом файле, если пост просто будет менятся каждую неделю и отправлятся. Так же если использовать чат, можете использовать функию copy_message, если использовать эту функцию не будет пометки, о том что сообщение переслано.